# simulating hook useState in React.Component scope problem of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good Morning,
I am trying to create a function in my class React.Component to allow modify a state value with a function.

```
   setCurrentIndex(update) {
        if (typeof update === 'function') {
            let newValue = update(this.state.currentIndex)
            this.setState({ currentIndex: newValue })
        } else {
            this.setState({ currentIndex: update })
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I execute this function in a child of my component, javascript says that this.state.currentIndex does not exist.

Here is my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        currentIndex: props.index
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Best Regards,
Fernando Moreno.

Comment: Are you passing the function to the child component via a prop?

Comment: Not sure if I misinterpreted your question, but react hooks are only available in functional components

Comment: Try to make `setCurrentIndex` and arrow function: `setCurrentIndex = update => {` And for next time please provide exact error you are getting.

Comment: Children don't inherit state/member functions from their parents automatically. You have to pass them via props

Comment: @HMR to change the function to arrow function did works fine! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to HMR, he replies to me the solution in a comment of the question, you just need to do this function as arrow function like this.

```
setCurrentIndex = (update) => {
    if (typeof update === 'function') {
        let newValue = update(this.state.currentIndex)
        this.setState({ currentIndex: newValue })
    } else {
        this.setState({ currentIndex: update })
    }
}
```

Thank you!